# executeScript get return variable and sendResponse in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is in a background script.
Everything seems to work down to the result, but my list variable seems to be empty no matter where I declare it in the scope. How do I use sendResponse to get the data back to my content script? What am I missing?

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

    list = [];
    // list available channels
    if (request.action.includes("channels")) {

      function inContent() {
        let elems = document.getElementsByClassName("name-sec");
        let channelsList = [];
        for (let ii = 0; ii < elems.length; ii++) {
          let channel = elems[ii];
          channelsList.push(channel.innerText);
        }
        return channelsList;
      }

      chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: `(${inContent})()` }, function (result) {
        list = result[0];
      });

      // list is empty
      sendResponse({action: `Channels List:${"\n"}${list.join("\n")}`})
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`chrome` API executes its callbacks asynchronously. Using an asynchronously-invoked callback **doesn't run it immediately**, it's similar to registering a one-time listener for the 'load' event and then the next statement starts running (calling sendResponse in your case) and uses the current value of `list` i.e. `[]`.

The solution is two-fold:

1. wait for the asynchronous callback;
2. tell onMessage to keep the channel open.

```js
if (...) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: `(${inContent})()` }, function (result) {
    list = result[0];
    sendResponse({action: `Channels List:${"\n"}${list.join("\n")}`});
  });
  return true;
}
```